# XPath to reach all nodes that are equal to the current one?

Tags: xslt, xpath

In an XML file, I have some parts of code that look like this:

```
<index indexName="Mots-matière">
  <term anchor="d0e7624">apprentissage automatique</term>
</index>
```

So, for example, there are many `<term>apprentissage automatique</term>` elements for whose I try to collect the `@anchor` attribute.

What is the good way to select all nodes that are equal to the current one?

I have in mind something like this, but I do miss something:

```
<xsl:for-each select="current() = //term">
  <xsl:value-of select="term/@anchor"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you are looking for is this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="//term[. = current()]">
       <xsl:value-of select="@anchor"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note how you would only need to select the `@anchor` attribute in this case, because you would be positioned on the `term` element within the `xsl:for-each`.

Of course, this would only work if your current node is one with the value you want.

Alternatively, you could use an `xsl:key`. At the top of your style sheet define a key like so...

```
<xsl:key name="terms" match="term" use="." />
```

Then you can do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('terms, current())">
       <xsl:value-of select="@anchor"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I made a mistake, the current node is'nt the one with the value I want. I'll start from this syntax to build the good one.